# PHP Name spacing problem with extends

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a file that declares a namespace in the beginning, then does an include of two supporting files that defines classes like X, Y, etc.

Now in the main file, after declaring the namespace, I can no longer create classes that extend X. I have not declared a namespace in X or Y, I assumed the definition at the top of the main file, before the includes, would take care of that? Shouldn't the class just default resolve to my namespace\X?

For example, in my PHP file I do this in the beginning:

```
namespace SGOAuth;
include 'OAuth.php';
include 'CURL.php';
```

And later a class I define in this file tries:

```
class MyClass extends CURL {...}
```

But I get the error: SGOAuth\CURL not found

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of describing the problem, can you please post some code sample that shows the problem?

Comment: @deceze `in adition`, not `instead` :)

Comment: Can you paste more code please? How do you call CURL? Are you sure the files are being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the `CURL` class is declared in the namespace `SGOAuth`, of course it won't exist in the namespace `SGOAuth`. Just including a file doesn't mean it's part of the namespace the file that includes the file is in (now that's a sentence ;)). That would make namespaces pointless.

`CURL.php`

```
// no namespace declaration, defaults to global namespace
class CURL { }
```

`foo.php`

```
// namespace declaration, all code *in this file* is in namespace Foo
namespace Foo;

// includes the CURL class, which is in the global namespace
include 'CURL.php';

new CURL;  // error, class does not exist in this namespace
new \CURL; // works
```

So `class CURL` by default is in the global namespace. To extend it, you need to `extends \CURL`.

Comment: ok so if the class does not exist in the current namespace, I have to prefix it with \ to get it to reference the class in the global namespace? I was under the impression from reading the docs that if it did not resolve in the current namespace it would try the global one automatically?

Comment: @pll Only for functions and constants, not classes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php